# Powershell Unzip file

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Im using below script to unzip file.But after unzipping I see my files are under "D:\Packages\Content\C_C\Jenkins\workspace\Call\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp" folder. How should I trim the folders and see the real content under "D:\Packages" folder directly

```
# Unzip the file to specified location
$shell_app=new-object -com shell.application 
$zip_file = $shell_app.namespace($file) 
$destination = $shell_app.namespace("D:\Packages") 
$destination.Copyhere($zip_file.items())
```

Comment: If you're copying [someone else's code](http://serverfault.com/a/201604/134295) it'd be nice if you at least gave them credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the nested folder structure inside the zip archive and extract each file separately. A recursive function is the usual way of doing this kind of thing. Something like this (untested):

```
function Expand-Files($Folder, $Target) {
  $Folder.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.IsFolder) {
      Expand-Files $_ $Target
    } else {
      $Target.CopyHere($_)
    }
  }
}

Expand-Files $zip_file $destination
```

Beware, though, that `CopyHere` runs asynchronously, i.e. the call returns immediately while the actual copy operation may still be running in the background.

You could also extract the nested folder tree to a temporary directory, and then copy all files to the actual destination folder:

```
Get-ChildItem $destination -Recurse |
  Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Move-Item -Destination $actualDestination
```

Using that approach (with .NET Framework 4.5 or newer installed) you could ditch the awkward/flaky `CopyHere` method and use [`ExtractToDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

$zipfile     = 'C:\path\to\your.zip'
$tempdir     = "$env:TEMP\some\folder"
$destination = 'D:\Packages'

[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $tempdir)
Get-ChildItem $tempdir -Recurse |
  Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Move-Item -Destination $destination
Remove-Item $tempdir -Recurse -Force
```

Or, you could simply use [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/):

```
& 7z.exe e -o"$destination" "$zipfile"
```

From the command help (emphasis mine):

> 7-Zip [32] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10
>
> Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...] [<@listfiles...>]
>
> <Commands>
>     a : Add files to archive
>     b : Benchmark
>     d : Delete files from archive
>     **e : Extract files from archive (without using directory names)**
>     h : Calculate hash values for files
>     i : Show information about supported formats
>     l : List contents of archive
>     rn : Rename files in archive
>     t : Test integrity of archive
>     u : Update files to archive
>     x : eXtract files with full paths
>   ...

Other packers probably have a similar option.

---

**Edit:** If you just want to extract things from a specific subfolder inside the zip archive you can pass the path (including the nested path) to the `Namespace` method:

```
$app = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
$items = $app.NameSpace('C:\path\to\your.zip\folder\inside\archive').Items()
$app.NameSpace('D:\Packages').CopyHere($items)
```

Comment: I Used your script.thanks you..It worked but I could see the all files which are under folders are copied to single folder. I need to trim till particular folder(i.e D:\Packages\Content\C_C\Jenkins\workspace\Call\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp)